# jQuery load() trouble IE only in same server

Tags: jquery, apache, configuration, load

So,
we have 4 servers

```
aruba shared: http://www.nogarabingo.it/test2.php
aruba dedicato: http://community.my-personaltrainer.it/test2.php
godaddy: http://stefanosilvestrini.com/test2.php
produzioneintegratori: http://www.produzioneintegratori.it/test2.php
```

In the 1st, 2nd and 3rd server all works fine (on all browsers). In the 4th server jQuery load() dosn't work in IE 6,7,8,9 but works fine in FFOX and Chrome.

Do you know if there are some issues or particular server configuration to fix this problem?

[Solved, Fixed, thanks to all]: The solution:

httpd.conf e php.ini

## EnableMMAP: Control whether memory-mapping is used to deliver # files (assuming that the underlying OS supports it).

## The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted # filesystems.  On some systems, turning it off (regardless of # filesystem) can improve performance; for details, please see # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablemmap

## EnableMMAP off

## EnableSendfile: Control whether the sendfile kernel support is # used to deliver files (assuming that the OS supports it).

## The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted # filesystems.  Please see # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

## EnableSendfile off

Comment: I opened the 4 urls, all seem ok

Comment: @Claude: In IE 6, 7, 8 or 9? Problem shows for me (in IE7)

Comment: It's baffled me, unfortunately. As you've limited it down to the server, I'd play with the `apache.conf` configuration on `produzioneintegratori.it`, so that it matches/closely resembles the configuration on another. Use the console in Chrome/ Firebug in Firefox to see what response headers differ.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as mentioned on the [.load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Comment: Looks like he is loading the page from the same domain to me.